# NHibernate Configuration Error - Connection String?

Tags: asp.net, sql, nhibernate

I am getting this error:

------ Test started: Assembly: ECEHire.Test.dll ------

Test 'ECEHire.Test.Tests.GenerateSchema_Fixture.Can_generate_schema' failed: NHibernate.HibernateException : Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 49.
  ----> System.ArgumentException : Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 49.
    at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.Execute(Action`1 scriptAction, Boolean export, Boolean justDrop)
    at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.Execute(Boolean script, Boolean export, Boolean justDrop)
    GenerateSchema_Fixture.vb(18,0): at ECEHire.Test.Tests.GenerateSchema_Fixture.Can_generate_schema()
    --ArgumentException
    at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
    at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
    at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String connectionString, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String value)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
    at NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()
    at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.Execute(Action`1 scriptAction, Boolean export, Boolean justDrop)

0 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, took 3.23 seconds (NUnit 2.5.10).

When I try to test my NHibernate configuration file.

The configuration file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=MyServerName;initial catalog=MyDatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI</property>
    <property name="connection.isolation">ReadCommitted</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The test that I am running is:

```
<Test()> _
Public Sub Can_generate_schema()

    Dim cfg = New Configuration()
    cfg.Configure()
    cfg.AddAssembly(GetType(Question).Assembly)
    Dim exp As NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport = New NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport(cfg)
    exp.Execute(False, True, False)

End Sub
```

I believe that this is a connection string error, but the connection string works as part of the web.config file for querying the database via ADO.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:-

1. Could it be something as simple as adding a ; (semi colon) e.g. `Integrated Security=SSPI;`
2. Or try changing to `Integrated Security=True;`
3. Or drop `connection.connection_string` and use `connection.connection_string_name`

In web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="db" connectionString="Data Source=MyServerName;initial catalog=MyDatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
</connectionStrings>

<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    ...
    <property name="connection.connection_string_name">db</property>
    ...
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Edit** The next thing to try is to make sure that the configuration file is being used in your test so try this:-

```
cfg.Configure(@"c:\hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Making sure that the path IS totally correct, If this fails then put a break point at this line:-

```
cfg.AddAssembly(GetType(Question).Assembly)
```

and then add this watch `cfg.Properties` and make sure that the connection string is present as a key value pair

**Edit2**
For unit testing you would need to copy local true and get path from executing assembly OR create an app.config and use:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration"
      type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property ../>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
</configuration>
```

For a web site you could do:-

```
cfg.Configure(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
```

To be honest there are lots of options and this is really another question!

Comment: Nope. Tried all three options. Also, I used Visual Studio to create the connection string, to ensure it was correct and testable. It gave me: Data Source=SqlSeverName;Initial Catalog=EDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True and it ested as successful.

Comment: OK, your first suggestion about pointing directly to the config file worked. Thanks. But, how do I put this into production now? Do I need to change the path when I put it into production? Can I create a more generic path? Also, it would not accept the connection string 'name'. Is that because I have a separate NHibernate config file, as opposed to using the web.config?

Comment: Please see edit 2, also if this has helped perhaps you could upvote and mark as accepted. ta.